Can something be at rest if it has a non-zero acceleration?
I think I have a decent grasp on the physics - I understand that something can be accelerating while stationary. That's the basis of my question. I just wanted to clarify some of the language used.
We say something is at rest if it is stationary. However, if something has zero velocity but non-zero acceleration, is it at rest?
Is a ball at rest in the instant it changes direction while bouncing off a wall, or is rest defined as when all derivatives of position are zero?

To clarify that the condition of being at rest may only last for a moment, physicist will sometimes use the term instantaneously at rest.

I have voted to reopen since this isn't a duplicate of the question I linked. However I'm not sure if it has answer since at rest is not a precisely defined term in physics. My interpretation would mean the velocity is zero but the higher derivatives of position can have any value. I think this is more linguistics than physics.

Thanks for your vote. I agree it could be classified as linguistics but I didn't see a benefit in posting on english.se as they probably don't realise the physics context as much.

Usually,
$$\text{at rest}\iff v^2=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\right)^2=0.$$
I've never read anything else, though of course "at rest" can be reference frame-dependent.
Yes, a ball would be at rest during the instant it is bouncing off a wall. If I throw a ball straight up under gravity, the ball would also be at rest at the instant its vertical velocity is zero, as well. It won't stay at rest very long in either case - an instant isn't very long and generally isn't physically interesting - but you can say that, for at least one time $t$ in the selected period, it was at rest.
